# passing params and data in scrapy post

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
payload={'hi':'hello world'}
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/anything', params=payload, data={'foo': 'bar'})
```

Is there a way to post parameters and data separately in a `FormRequest` in Scrapy, I checked the documentation ([scrapy request docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)) and I am only seeing `formdata` to post data,can I send parameters as well?

anther question do websites care if I pile params and data into one dictionary in POST ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` are send in url like

```
http://httpbin.org/anything?hi=hello+world
```

so you can create this url manually in `Scrapy`

If you print `r.text` and `r.url` in your code then you should see params in url

```
{
  # ... rest ...
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?hi=hello+world"
}

http://httpbin.org/anything?hi=hello+world
```

---

You can't send `params` in dictionary `data`.

---

Minimal code which shows it

```
import requests

payload = {'hi':'hello world'}
data = {'foo': 'bar'}

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/anything', params=payload, data=data)

print(r.text)
print(r.url)
```